# How to redirect to a new page from alert popup in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having a radio button group of three radio buttons with same name but different ids as follows:

```
<p class="custom-form">
        <input type="radio" name="generate_paper" id="generate_paper_manual" value="manual" checked="checked" onChange="change_paper_generate_type();" /> <label for="generate_paper_manual">Manual</label>
        <input type="radio" name="generate_paper" id="generate_paper_auto" value="auto" onChange="change_paper_generate_type();" />  <label for="generate_paper_auto">Auto Generate</label>
        <input type="radio" name="generate_paper" id="generate_own_paper" value="own"/> <label for="generate_paper_own">Own Paper</label> 
      </p>
```

Now I want to show a confirmation popup message "Do you want to generate own test questions ?" and Yes/No button.
If user clicks on Yes button then the page should be redirected to URL "/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/users/view_users.php". 
If user clicks on No the opened popup should get close.
Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Now I want to show a confirmation popup message* when? ok, now you want to do it, but when do you want to show the confirmation message?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED, try:

```
if (confirm("Do you want to generate own test questions ?"))
    document.location.href = "/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/users/view_users.php";
```

I'm wrong with function name

Comment: `prompt` is not what he's looking for. It's for writing free text, not Yes/No dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm):

> `result = window.confirm(message);`
>
> - `message` is the optional string to be displayed in the dialog.
> - `result` is a boolean value indicating whether OK or Cancel was selected (true means OK).

```
if (window.confirm("Do you want to generate own test questions ?"))
    window.location.href = "/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/users/view_users.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Confirm as dialog box. If it return true redirect to wanted page.

```
if(confirm("YOUR QUESTION?"))
{
document.location.href="URL OF PAGE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javascript popup boxes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) (window.confirm) or, if you prefer, [jquery dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or other DOM-based dialogues.

To change url you can set window.location.href:

```
window.location.href = "/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/users/view_users.php";
```